# is for loop allowed in autoValue Collection2?

Tags: meteor-collection2

Would it be possible to create 'updatesHistory.$.date' (where $ is from 0 to n) using autoValue? My for statement looks like it cannot be executed in autovalue function.

```
// Whenever the "content" field is updated, automatically
// update a history array.
updatesHistory: {
type: [Object],
optional: true,
autoValue: function() {
  var content = this.field("content");
  if (content.isSet) {
    if (this.isInsert) {
      return [{
          date: new Date,
          content: content.value
        }];
    } else {
      return {
        $push: {
          date: new Date,
          content: content.value
        }
      };
    }
  } else {
    this.unset();
  }
}
},
'updatesHistory.$.date': {
type: Date,
optional: true
},
'updatesHistory.$.content': {
type: String,
optional: true
},
```